# JQuery UI Dialog appearing under galleria on Android

Tags: jquery-ui, galleria, android-browser

Pretty standard galleria / JQueryUI code to display a dialog on a gallery page.  Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nHsM3/

Dialog appearing under the galleria gallery on Android 3.1 Samsung Galaxy 10.1

I have experimented around with the z-order of the dialog div.  No luck.  Does anyone know of a fix for this?

FYI - not seeing this on Galaxy Tab 7.7 Android 3.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The eventual fix was to detect Android 3.1 and set the [transition](http://galleria.io/docs/options/transition/#built-in-transitions) to none.  Look like the default fade is causing something funny to happen to the z-index.